# T-SQL: Conditional Existential grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I need to get all the `Room_IDs` in `TABLE_A` where the two 2 or more last `Status` of each instance of `Room_IDs` are consecutively vacant (relative to `Inspection_Date`) and does not exist in `TABLE_B`.

This is a simplified table I am using as an example:

**TABLE_A**:

```
  Room_Id   Status    Inspection_Date
  -------------------------------------
    1        vacant      5/15/2015
    2        occupied    5/21/2015
    2        vacant      1/19/2016
    1        occupied   12/16/2015
    4        vacant      3/25/2016
    3        vacant      8/27/2015
    1        vacant      4/17/2016
    3        vacant     12/12/2015
    3        vacant      3/22/2016
    4        occupied    2/2/2015
    4        vacant      3/24/2015
```

**TABLE_B**:

```
  Room_Id   Status    Inspection_Date
  ------------------------------------
    1        vacant       5/15/2015
    2        occupied     5/21/2015
    2        vacant       1/19/2016
    1        vacant      12/16/2015
    1        vacant       4/17/2016
```

My result should look like this:

```
   Room_Id  Status  Inspection_Date
   ---------------------------------
    3       vacant      8/27/2015
    3       vacant     12/12/2015
    3       vacant      3/22/2016
    4       occupied    2/2/2015
    4       vacant      3/24/2015
    4       vacant      3/25/2016
```

Here is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A (`Room_Id` int, 
                      `Status` varchar(55), 
                      `Inspection_Date` varchar(55)
                     );

INSERT INTO TABLE_A (`Room_Id`, `Status`, `Inspection_Date`)
VALUES  (1, 'vacant',      '5/15/2015'),
        (2, 'occupied',    '5/21/2015'),
        (2, 'vacant',      '1/19/2016'),
        (1, 'occupied',   '12/16/2015'),
        (4, 'vacant',      '3/25/2016'),
        (3, 'vacant',      '8/27/2015'),
        (1, 'vacant',      '4/17/2016'),
        (3, 'vacant',     '12/12/2015'),
        (3, 'vacant',      '3/22/2016'),
        (4, 'occupied',       '2/2/2015'),
        (4, 'vacant',      '3/24/2015');

CREATE TABLE TABLE_B (`Room_Id` int, 
                      `Status` varchar(55),         
                      `Inspection_Date` varchar(55)
                     );

INSERT INTO TABLE_B (`Room_Id`, `Status`, `Inspection_Date`)
VALUES
        (1, 'vacant',      '5/15/2015'),
        (2, 'occupied',    '5/21/2015'),
        (2, 'vacant',      '1/19/2016'),
        (1, 'vacant',      '12/16/2015'),
        (1, 'vacant',      '4/17/2016'),;
```

Comment: The room_id dont exist in table_b?  Or are you wanting to match on two or maybe all three columns?

Comment: Room_ID is not in table_B, thanks for asking

Comment: If you have a column like `Inspection_Date` - you should use the **most appropriate** datatype - and `varchar(55)` certainly **is NOT.** Use `DATE` (if you only need the date), or `DATETIME2(n)` if you need the time portion, too. Also: drop those annoying backticks - that's MySQL, they have no meaning or no need in T-SQL for those

Comment: @marc_s This was to facilitate the use.. I obviously use a Date datatype on my table. also here the back ticks are there because I copy-pasted the column names from an earlier part of the message stackoverflow uses them as "mini-markdown formatting tools" for `code`. Thank you though ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this approach:

```
with Rooms as (
    select
        Room_Id, Status,
        row_number() over (partition by Room_Id order by Inspection_Date desc) as rn
    from TABLE_A
), Candidates as (
    select Room_Id from Rooms group by Room_Id
    having sum(case when rn in (1, 2) and Status = 'vacant' then 1 else null end) = 2
)
select * from TABLE_A
where Room_Id in (select Room_Id from Candidates except select Room_Id from TABLE_B)
order by Room_Id, Inspection_Date desc
```

See the query in operation here: http://rextester.com/VXBRFF91880

Comment: I have previously tried that but unfortunately the logic did not work, thank you for your help anyways!

Comment: @Hamza I did indeed accidentally leave out a critical part of the `where` clause which you probably already noticed. But other than that I'd love to know which part doesn't match up with your requirement.

Comment: yes you are right sorry I had to take care of other things, but i do see the problem with my code. thank you !

Answer (score 1):

This gives the results you are looking for based on the sample data.  ps Thanks for including the create table and insert statements.

```
With cteA As
(
Select *, Row_Number() Over (Partition By Room_ID, Status Order By Inspection_Date Desc) RowNum From Table_A 
)
Select * From Table_A Where Room_Id In
(
Select Room_Id 
    From cteA
    Where Room_Id Not In (Select Room_Id From Table_B) 
        And Status = 'vacant' And RowNum > 1 
)
    Order By Room_Id, Inspection_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT DISTINCT a.Room_Id,
        COUNT(a.Inspection_Date) OVER(PARTITION BY a.Room_Id,a.[Status]  ORDER BY a.[Status]) as d
FROM TABLE_A a
FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_B b
    ON a.Room_Id = b.Room_Id and a.Inspection_Date = b.Inspection_Date
WHERE b.Room_Id IS NULL and a.[Status] = 'vacant'
)

SELECT a.*
FROM cte c
INNER JOIN TABLE_A a
    ON a.Room_Id = c.Room_Id
```

Output:

```
Room_Id Status      Inspection_Date
4       vacant      3/25/2016
3       vacant      8/27/2015
3       vacant      12/12/2015
3       vacant      3/22/2016
4       occupied    2/2/2015
4       vacant      3/24/2015
```

Answer (score 0):

all of the answers were correct to a certain extant but never gave me the last two of each instance of `Room_IDs` as `Status` vacant:

I was able to find the answer

```
         WITH lastDate AS ( SELECT Room_ID  ,MAX(Inspection_Date) AS [date]
                        FROM TableA
                        GROUP BY Room_ID), 
          prevLastDate AS ( SELECT a.Room_ID  ,MAX(Inspection_Date) AS [date]
                            FROM TableA a
                            INNER JOIN lastDate ON a.Room_ID = lastDate.Room_ID and a.Inspection_Date < lastDate.[date]
                            GROUP BY a.Room_ID), 
          lastDateVacant AS ( SELECT Room_ID   
                              FROM TableA
                              WHERE Room_ID IN ( SELECT Room_ID FROM lastDate) 
                              AND Inspection_Date IN ( SELECT [date] FROM lastDate) 
                              AND Status = 'Vacant'),
          prevLastDateVacant AS ( SELECT Room_ID   
                                  FROM TableA
                                  WHERE Room_ID IN ( SELECT Room_ID FROM prevLastDate) 
                                  AND Inspection_Date IN ( SELECT [date] FROM prevLastDate) 
                                  AND Status = 'Vacant')

    SELECT a.* 
    FROM TableA a 
    INNER JOIN lastDateVacant 
        ON a.Room_ID = lastDateVacant.Room_ID
    INNER JOIN prevLastDateVacant 
        ON a.Room_ID = prevLastDateVacant.Room_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN preservation.. AS b
        ON a.Room_ID = b.Room_ID    
    WHERE b.Room_ID IS NULL 
    ORDER BY a.Room_ID ASC, a.Inspection_Date DESC
```

Comment: I don't believe that's a valid SQL Server query.

Comment: @shawnt00 it is, I am using it now in prod, I made sure to check manually.

Comment: I have fixed the syntax a little and double checked .. it still working
      1. For each room in TableA we select the last date (as lastDate)
      2. For each room in TableA we select previous date (as prevLastDate)
      3. We get Room_ID from lastDate which has the Status in 'vacant' (as lastDateVacant)
      4. We get Room_ID from prevLastDate which has the Status in 'vacant' (as prevLastDateVacant)
      5. We filter to only have Room_ID which are in lastDateVacant and prevLastDateVacant (inner)
      6. We filter to only have Room_ID which are not in TableB (left outer + IS NULL)

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231/add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructors

Comment: @shawnt00 I copied the wrong query here sorry about that .. but like I previously said I have fixed the syntax. and pasted the correct TSQL query.

Comment: I can spot a few problems with your query.

Comment: Please see the rextester link in my answer for a demonstration of the problems with your query.